# How to get series of e-mails from Outlook to pdf with attachments and in ascending date order?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I recently changed computers from one running:

- Windows 10 Pro 64 with MS Office Pro 2019 and Adobe Acrobat XI Pro

to

- Windows 11 Pro 64 with MS Office Pro Plus 2021 and Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 2020 Continuous Release

All of this software runs on my computer with perpetual licenses, not in the "cloud" with subscriptions.

In the previous setup, if I wanted to make a pdf file from a series of e-mails, I did:

- In Outlook, put the e-mails in a folder.
- Sort the folder in ascending date order.
- Select all the folder contents.
- Right-click in the folder list and select "Convert to Adobe PDF".

The result would be a pdf file containing all the e-mails in the same order they appeared in the folder. Attachments to the e-mails are attached in the pdf file and appear listed in the e-mail headers with their filenames clickable to open them. (This treatment of attachments makes this procedure far superior to printing the e-mails to pdf, which lists attachments, but does not attach those attachments in the pdf file.)

If I now do the same procedure, instead of an ordinary pdf file, I get a pdf portfolio, which is a file that contains a sequence of pdf files, one for each e-mail. In Acrobat, the portfolio provides a list of the files with the dates of the e-mails, and it is sorted in descending date order. I am able to change the sort order of that list, but when I save, close, and reopen the portfolio, it always comes up with the files listed in descending date order.

In order to convert the portfolio to a single pdf file, I can use Acrobat's "File > Create > Combine Files into a Single PDF ..." and then add only the portfolio file. This extracts the files from the portfolio and appends them in sequence into an ordinary pdf file. The "Combine Files" window gives me a list of the files to be combined, and that list is in alphabetical order by the subject lines of the e-mails. There is a "Modified" column in that list, but it is the date and time that the portfolio was added in this window, the same for all the e-mails, so I can't use it to sort the list.

When I click "Combine", the pdf file is generated containing the e-mails, but they appear in alphabetical order of their subject lines, which is a useless mess.

Is there a way to get those e-mails into a date-sorted pdf file, like I used to do easily in Acrobat XI?

Comment: Did you use any add-in for Outlook? I didn’t find the button "Convert to Adobe PDF".

Comment: @Jayce - Thank you for your question, which led me to find the solution to the problem. See my answer to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to the comment by Jayce led me to the solution.

Short answer: In the main Outlook window (i.e., not the window of an opened e-mail), go to "Acrobat > Change Conversion Settings" and uncheck "Output Adobe PDF Portfolio when creating a new PDF file".

Long answer:

When Acrobat is installed, it places and add-in into MS Word, Excel, and Outlook. The add-in puts "Acrobat" in the main menu across the top of the window and allows for outputting pdf files. For Outlook, it also puts "Convert to Adobe PDF" in the context menu of the list of e-mails. In the previous setup, that generated an ordinary pdf file. In the new setup, it made a portfolio, even if it only contained one e-mail. For a single e-mail, I could get around that by opening the e-mail and outputting the pdf using the "Acrobat" tab in the main menu. That made an ordinary e-mail.

When I wrote that paragraph in response to Jayce's comment, it occurred to me to check out the "Acrobat" tab in the main menu of the main Outlook window, which I hadn't done before. When I selected one e-mail and did "Acrobat > Selected Messages > Create New PDF", it still made a portfolio of that one e-mail, just like when using "Convert to Adobe PDF" in the context menu in the list of e-mails. I presume the reason for the different default behaviors -- make a portfolio when in the list of e-mails, but make an ordinary pdf file when in the window of an e-mail -- is because the former can be working with multiple e-mails, while the latter can only be working with one.

Then I noticed another item in the menu of the "Acrobat" tab in the main Outlook window: "Change Conversion Settings". There, I found a setting for "Output Adobe PDF Portfolio when creating a new PDF file". Of course, it was checked. I unchecked it, then tested "Convert to Adobe PDF" again. It now makes an ordinary pdf file, not a portfolio, whether I do it with a selection of one e-mail or several.

And -- BINGO! -- in the pdf made of several e-mails, they appear in the same order as in the Outlook folder. Mission accomplished.

When I set up Office on the new computer, I went through the settings available through "File > Options". It did not occur to me look for special settings in the "Acrobat" tab of the main menus of Office after installing Acrobat. Had I done that, I would have seen that setting and would not have had this problem.

Thank you Jayce for the question in your comment, which led me to this solution.

Comment: Amazing! And I am so glad to know this, thanks for your sharing.